# Obtener datos de una celda de un datagridview en el evento CurrentCellChanged en Vb?

Tags: vb.net

tengo el siguiente evento:

```
Private Sub zGrid_CurrentColumnChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles zGrid.CurrentCellChanged
    Dim CodArt As String = zGrid.Item(0, e.RowIndex).Value.ToString()
End Sub
```

pero no me reconoce el `e.RowIndex` porque esta es heredada de  `DataGridViewCellEventArgs`

y si paso por parametro `DataGridViewCellEventArgs` en vez de EventArgs me da error el programa

estoy intentando que al cambiar de celda con las teclas de navegacion haga un calculo con el cod art de esa celda

Comment: No se entiende exactamente cual es el evento que quieres capturar: cuando se edita una celda manualmente? o cuando se selecciona una celda en particular? (SelectedCellChanged)

Comment: Cuando me muevo entre celdas con las botones direccionales del teclado. @AgustinM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una **solución posible** es capturar el evento **SelectionChanged** del objeto **DataGridView**.

*La cuestión es que el mismo se dispara en varias ocasiones (por ej: **cuando se selecciona una celda, o una fila entera, o multiples celdas**)* así que puedes limitar dicha acción **modificando dos propiedades** del DataGridView: **MultiSelect** y **SelectionMode**.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Luego el código que debes utilizar es este:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
Private Sub DataGridView1_SelectionChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.SelectionChanged
    If DataGridView1.SelectedCells.Count <> 0 Then
        Dim CodArt As String = DataGridView1.SelectedCells(0).Value.ToString()
    End If
End Sub
```

**EDIT:**

El código que programé en el evento **SelectionChanged** es un "similar" a lo que tu has programado pero dicho código está mal si tu intención es que, al moverte por una fila celda a celda, sea capturado una columna en particular y no cada celda.

Para decirlo de otro modo con el código presente arriba defines a la variable "CodArt" con el valor de la celda a la que te estas moviendo.

Si tu intención es recuperar la columna "CodArt" de la fila en la que te encuentras, independientemente de la celda el código a utilizar es el siguiente:

```
Private Sub DataGridView1_SelectionChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.SelectionChanged
    If DataGridView1.SelectedCells.Count <> 0 Then
        'N de Fila:
        Dim NFila As Integer = DataGridView1.SelectedCells(0).RowIndex

        'Con el N de Fila, me posiciono y recupero la Columna 'CodArt'
        Dim CodArt As String = DataGridView1.Rows(NFila).DataBoundItem("CodArt").ToString

    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Hola excelente la propuesta aunque la simplificaria aún mas, solo poniendo esta linea de código

```
Dim CodArt As String = introducir el código aquí DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).DataBoundItem("CodArt").ToString
```

Para no crear otra variable, utilizo `e`.